# How to remove Windows and GRUB problem

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, removing

At the moment I have Ubuntu and Windows 7 installed on my hard drive. Since I don't want to split my memory I want to remove Windows, but I have no idea how to do it since I am new to Linux.

Another problem I had after installing Ubuntu was that the GRUB bootloader didn't work so I googled for a bit of advice, and now I think I have an older version of GRUB. Is there a way to update it?

This is how my drive looks like at the moment:

[image]

Comment: But is Grub working right now? Normally it auto-updates with the OS, so you don't need to worry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The first thing you should do is to back up any files you want to keep from the My Documents Folder.**

You may need to repair your GRUB which can be done by [following these guidelines](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Next, in gparted, the programme you used in your screen shot in your question, Right click on the Windows 7 partition `/dev/sda2` and select **unmount** next right click on the same partition and select **delete** to remove the partition. **This will completely wipe windows ad ALL files on the windows partition**

Now you will have a blank space on your hard disk where Windows used to be. Next you will want to resize the partition with Ubuntu on it to reclaim the unused disk space.

*I have never done this, so you may need to format it first. I'm afraid that you will have to either look it up or work it out with trial and error. **Please see Jez W's comment below***

Comment: He mentioned having trouble with grub. If grub isn't correctly installed, he might have problems booting into Ubuntu (but it is unlikely). I'd suggest he also re-installs grub with `boot-repair` just to avoid such problems.

Comment: @JoãoAndré That could be a good idea, and worth a try. I'll edit my answer. Thanks

Comment: If I remember correctly from doing something similar, when extending the partition the space needs to be free rather than formatted. Also, when extending leftwards it's generally a good idea to back up anything important on the partition being extended - if extending to the right the extra space just gets appended, whereas the data is actually moved when resizing leftwards (so that things at the start of the old partition are now at the start of the new) - it takes a while and there's a (rather small) risk involved, hence backup - but it should work.

Comment: Wow! Thank you all for the great help. My solution was to create a Ubuntu bootable USB and just delete everything and install Ubuntu new (extending just would not work). Now everything works great.